# How do to input values and strings into class object? Getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, object, vector

I'm trying to add String name, long phoneNumber, and String comment to the Contact object, then place it into object array.

```
public class VectorOfContacts implements ProjTwo
{
    Contact[] contacts;
    public void addContact(Contact c)
    {

            if(isFull());
            incrementCapacity();
            size++;
            String name = "";
            long number = 0;
            String comment = "";
            c.setName(name);
            c.setPhoneNumber(number);
            c.setComment(comment);
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
            {
                if (contacts[i] == null)
                {
                    contacts[i] = c;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Added to input");

    }
}
```

However, I get a NullPointerException starting in c.setName(name).

Comment: make sure you are passing valid instance of Contact class to addContact method.

Comment: stacktrace or gtfo ;D

Comment: `if(isFull()); // <-- semicolon terminates the block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing an instance of a Contact into the method.  It's likely you're doing this:

```
Contact c;
...
addContact(c);
```

In this case, you're actually passing null into the addContact method.  You need to something like this instead:

```
Contact c = new Contact();
...
addContact(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the method 'setName' in Contact just does this:

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

If that is the case, then c, must be null. This would mean that the problem is in the method which calls 'addContact(Contact c)'. Somehow, it is passing a null argument.